# Copy exe from one project to another's debug output directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exe

I have two projects, ProjOne.exe and ProjTwo.exe.  I want to build ProjOne.exe and it know that it's dependant on ProjTwo.exe so that it will copy ProjTwo.exe when it goes to build ProjOne.exe.

I also have a ProjThree.dll that it already does that for perfectly.  But this in only because the dll is referenced by ProjOne.

Any way to do this like it does with DLLs/OCXs?  Or is this going to be some POST build scripting?  :)  If so please give examples of the script I would use.

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you do this by including both projects in a solution and then setting the solutions output path property appropriately?

Comment: They are in the same solution.  I never thought about setting the output path directly to the ProjOne debug directory.  I think that might some way bite me in the...  ProjTwo is used by a few different projects in different solutions as well..  :/  Though this will work as a quick and dirty solution it will not do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to **Project ProjTwo Properties** -> **Build Events** --> **Post-build event command line** :

```
echo f | xcopy /y "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)ProjOne\bin\Debug$(TargetFileName)"
```

When you build ProjTwo, then it copies ProjTwo.exe to Debug folder of ProjOne

Comment: I figured this is what I would have to do and there was not something built in to accomplish this automatically.  Thanks!

Comment: @ArvoBowen thanks for the edit, I have my VS in Spanish so I tried to translate it as best as I can to English.

Comment: np, I also thought I should add in most cases there should not be a need for xcopy.  Due to the lack of a needed switch on xcopy (like /I but for files instead of directories) one would probably just go with the copy command like so... `copy /Y "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)ProjOne\bin\Debug$(TargetFileName)"`

Answer (score 10):

I ended up using ganchito55's method and it worked great.  I then quickly realized that it would not suit my purposes when dealing with multiple files (such as debug files, etc).  I also wanted to account for building in `DEBUG` and `RELEASE`.

I ended up doing the following...

### 1) **Dig down to the project properties on ProjTwo:**

**Right click on project** -> **Properties** -> **Build Events**

### 2) **Add the following lines to the "Post-build event command line" box:**

Copy ALL files used in the ProjTwo to the ProjOne output directory when building `DEBUG` output.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)*.*" "$(SolutionDir)ProjOne\bin\Debug\"
```

Copy ALL files used in the ProjTwo to the ProjOne output directory when building `RELEASE` output.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)*.*" "$(SolutionDir)ProjOne\bin\Release\"
```